# Value array json: How to get elements with Angular js?

Tags: json, angularjs

The call on the api returns this json:

```
[
{
    "RESULT": {
        "TYPES": [
            "bigint",
            "varchar",
            "varchar",
            "varchar",
            "varchar",
            "varchar",
            "date",
            "varchar",
            "int",
            "int",
            "varchar"
        ],
        "HEADER": [
            "kvk",
            "bedrijfsnaam",
            "adres",
            "postcode",
            "plaats",
            "type",
            "anbi",
            "status",
            "kvks",
            "sub",
            "website"
        ],
        "ROWS": [
            [
                "273121520000",
                "Kinkrsoftware", <-- this is the value i want
                "Oude Trambaan 7",
                "2265CA",
                "Leidschendam",
                "Hoofdvestiging",
                null,
                null,
                "27312152",
                "0",
                null
            ]
        ]
    }
}
]
```

I can't change the api code.

I am using Angular and I can't see to get access to the values.

This is my controller:

```
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log, kvkInfo) {

  kvkInfo.success(function(status, data) { 

        $scope.name = status;
    $scope.bedrijf = data;
    $scope.status = status;
      });


});
```

I have tried

data.RESULT.ROW, data.RESULT.ROW[1], data.RESULT[0].ROW, data.RESULT[0].ROW[1], data.ROW[1]

How can i get this element?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you get starts with `[`, so it's an array. So you need `data[0]`.

The first element of this array (`data[0]`) is an object (it starts with `{`) which has a RESULT attribute. So you can use `data[0].RESULT`.

The value of the RESULT attribute is another object which has a `ROWS` attribute (Note the final `S`). So you can use `data[0].RESULT.ROWS`.

The value of ROWS is an array, containing another array, so you need `data[0].RESULT.ROWS[0][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your api result is wrapped in an array, so you have to save the first element of it to the scope instead of the whole array.